# Gradle build failed to produce an .apk file while connecting AppCenter to GitHub

Tags: android, flutter, dart-pub, visual-studio-app-center

I want to build a flutter app through AppCenter by connecting to github, but getting this error:

> Gradle build failed to produce an .apk file. It's likely that this
> file was generated under /Users/runner/work/1/s/build, but the tool
> couldn't find it.

Answer (score 0):

Flutter is not supported by App Center, see this issue [Flutter Support](https://github.com/microsoft/appcenter/issues/67). There are ways to get the build working, you will find instruction from the issue.

Comment: Before, it through error "Unsupported Android Plugin version: 4.1.1.".

Comment: i try build by flutter in VScode, i through error "Gradle build failed to produce an .apk file. It's likely that this file was generated under <root-project>\build, but the tool couldn't find it."